# Vue3 Watching route not working on production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, watch

I have this bit of code. Im using it to watch if my project edit/create pages lead to certain pages, and if so I want to retain the data in them(not reset the project). otherwise every other page should reset the project in project create.

Array of excluded routes that should not trigger the deletion. On my local environment, this all works perfectly. If i run npm run production locally, it also works.

However on production environment on the live server, doesent work. I dont even get the two console logs in the watch function printed at all. Referring to these;
console.log('accessed from a route where data should clear');
console.log('simply watching route, from', from.name, 'to', to.name);

I have no idea why, any help is greatly appreciated. Does watch $route not work in production or something?

```
  excludedRoutes: [
                'hsAssetTypeCreate',
                'hsAssetTypeEdit',
                'clientCreate',
                'contactCreate',
                'tradeContractorCreate',
                'userCreate',
                'formCreate',
                'projectCreate'
            ],
```

```
   watch: {
        $route(to, from) {
            console.log('accessed from a route where data should clear');
            console.log('simply watching route, from', from.name, 'to', to.name);
            if (this.excludedRoutes.includes(from.name) && !this.excludedRoutes.includes(to.name)) {
                console.log('data cleared',this.excludedRoutes.includes(from.name),this.excludedRoutes.includes(to.name));
                this.$store.commit('modals/setSelectedForms', {
                    formsModal: [],
                    workersModal: [],
                    assetsModal: [],
                    clientsModal: [],
                    tradeContractorsModal: []
                });
                //this.$store.commit('setProject', {});
                this.$store.dispatch('resetProject');
                this.$store.commit('modals/setunsavedChanges', false);
                this.$store.commit('modals/closeAll');
            }else{
                console.log('data shouldnt have been cleared');
            }
        },
}
```

Comment: Do you use vite?
In that case, it's normal, vite remove console.log when he build the project. I can provide a solution if it's the case.

Comment: Not using vite, old project, using laravel mix/webpack

Comment: If you search for console in your project, did you see nothing inside a conf file? Maybe it is disabled like this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/doeas-npm-run-prod-removes-consolelog.

Or otherwise, try to add a top level console.log, like in the app.vue created lifecyclehook. And see if you can see it in prod.

Comment: console.logs work on other pages so i dont think its that. Im more wondering if there is something that doesent work when using watch and $route like I am

Comment: Well in that case it's pretty clear that yes the problem occur inside the watch or maybe you didn't deploy correctly the new version on production.
Try in the same component to setup a log inside a created for example.